# Passing in a callback after changing state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently trying to convert the React + Material UI + Firebase template found on the Material UI website. Right now I am trying [(codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-react-hooks-7cm6j) to open the dialog component for the Sign Up. The current [setup](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) for [App.js](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase/blob/master/src/components/App/App.js) has the function:

```
openDialog = (dialogId, callback) => {
  const dialog = this.state[dialogId];

  if (!dialog || dialog.open === undefined || null) {
    return;
  }

  dialog.open = true;

  this.setState({ dialog }, callback);

};
```

And I am trying to convert it to use hooks like such, but not sure how with the callback:

```
const openDialog = e => {
  setDialog({ ...dialog, [e.target.name]: true });
};
```

Comment: Hi Brennan, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your callback in `useEffect` hook. You need to pass `dialog.open` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook which will only run when `dialog.open` changes,

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (dialog.open) {
    callback();    //This is where you call your callback function
  }
},[dialog.open,callback])  //pass your function as dependency
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hsnhjc)

Comment: @Joseph D., Thanks for your edit, I have just added demo.

Comment: You need to track `dialog.open` as well.

Comment: @Clarity, Yes, you are correct, updated the answer. **The first one is generalized `useEffect` which will run for every state change.** After passing `dialog.open` as dependency we ensure that `useEffect` will run only when `dialog.open` changes.

Comment: Leaving out `callback` will also result in eslint hooks warning...